# Multithread Read file csv and update/upsert mongodb using spring batch

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch, mongotemplate

I am using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb and wanted to make a multithread scenario or another way to make the operation quickly.
I'm reading a cvs file and then I do an update/upsert in mongodb. For now it is in sync
Does anyone have any examples or tips?

Comment: Multithreading won't make it faster. I suggest you concentrate on getting a correct single-threaded implementation and then look to see how you can improve it, e.g. by input buffering, JDBC batches, good SQL practices, &c.

Comment: this I have already implemented. The database is mongodb, it doesn't have sql, jdbc.... I'm using BulkOperations